# Can't connect to WMI provider . You do not have permission or the server is unreachable

Tags: windows-10, configurationmanager, sql-server-2017

I have a windows 10 machine and sql server express version 13.0.4. I can't find Sql Server configuration manager.
when I search C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc. I get an error can't connect to WMI provider . You do not have permission or the  server is unreachable.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with SQL Configuration Manager

First you will need to open the **Command Prompt in Adminstrator Mode**.
This is important because the following command will not work.

This this the following command

mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\ **number** \Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"

Note that you will need to replace the **number** parameter with the version of SQL Server you are using, which should be 140.

So type

**mofcomp "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"**

After executing this command the last word you should see is " Done ".

If you see Fail that's because your not in administrator mode.

Find more info here

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/956013/error-message-when-you-open-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-sql-se